# Unable to install powerline in Vim

Tags: vim

I have this in my config file:

```
 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
 call vundle#begin()

 Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

 Plugin 'helino/vim-nasm'
 Plugin 'elixir-lang/vim-elixir'
 Plugin 'powerline/powerline'
 call vundle#end()
```

And then I did this:

```
:source %
:PluginInstall
```

But the plugin powerline is still not installed, it's not visible.

https://github.com/powerline/powerline

Comment: Installation of powerline requires adding pip package and fonts https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html  
Might I suggest using better alternative https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline

Comment: Is this your complete .vimrc regarding Vundle? Vundle requires the lines `set nocompatible` and `filetype off` before calling `vundle#begin()` and after `vundle#end()` the lines `filetype plugin indent on` are required. At least this is stated on the github page.

Answer (score 1):

Powerline only display when plugin like NERDtree is active. If you want to display it every time add this line to your `.vimrc` file.

```
set laststatus=2
```

Comment: but it still displays the standard black vim status bar.

Comment: Are you sure powerline is installed? If not try to clone it from github and place it into the .vim dir

Comment: Please provide .vimrc file